# How do you reference a html tag in php?

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I want to put in a conditional statement in the below code in order to prevent the PHP Post from running if there is no selection of the "branches" radio buttons.

I can't find the syntax to do this correctly.

I'm not sure how to refer to a HTML tag in a conditional statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("Data has been submitted!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Reference Stats Input</h1>
<form  method="post">
<h2>Select Branch</h2>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="AR">AR</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="BK">BK</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="BR">BR</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="EM">EM</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="MD">MD</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="PT">PT</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="UR">UR</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="branches" value="WA">WA</label><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

Type of Reference question:<select name="refquestion" <br><br>
<option value="ADULT">ADULT</option>
<option value="CHILD">CHILD</option>
<option value="JUVENILE">JUVENILE</option>
</select><br><br>

<input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="INPUT">

<?php
if(!empty("branches"){
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","REDACTED");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("refstats", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO reftable (branch, statcat)
VALUES
('$_POST[branches]','$_POST[refquestion]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

mysql_close($con)
}
?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['branches']) { // do something }`

Comment: PHP is processed on the server before anything EVER reaches your web browser. PHP controls HTML, HTML can only send POST or GET data to the server for PHP to process. PHP will never be aware of "on-page" HTML code. Javascript is used for live "on-page" manipulation of HTML

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this with php, php is serverside and only knows the selection after you posted it.

You have to do this with an eventhandler in javascript. Im going to give you an example with jQuery to illustrate it, I'll see if I can get it back to native JS:

```
// jQuery style (and therefor requires jQuery to work)
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    if( $('[name="branches"]:selected').length === 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('please select a branch');
    }
});

// Or native Javascript (this isn't tested 100%, but something like this):
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit=function(){
    // get all options
    var options = document.getElementsByName("branches");
    var itemChecked = false; // start with false, se to true if there is a selected option
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].checked) { // if one option is found
            itemChecked  = true; // set to true
            break; // no need to continue the loop
        }
    }
    return itemChecked
};
```

---

You could always make on option default selected :)
**IMPORTANT**: Never trust javascript!! Always doublecheck clientside information serverside. Clientside information should ALWAYS be considered evil and you should make sure it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something to the affect of:

```
if(!isset($_POST['branches']) { 
// do something
}

elseif(isset($_POST['branches']) { 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","REDACTED");
// continue with rest of code
```